# What are the options we have if we want to have the ability to recover deleted data for more than 14 days?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, backup

As I know that SharePoint online keeps deleted content including lists, libraries, files and items for 93 days to be recovered from recycle bins or from the SharePoint admin "Delete sites" section. after that the content will be deleted from the tenant, but Microsoft will keep the deleted content for 14 days and we can ask Microsoft to recover the content. but what if we want to expand the 14 days ? does Microsoft provide a paid plan for this? or the only way is to find a 3rd party tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want to expand the 14-day retention period for deleted data in SharePoint Online, Microsoft does not currently offer a paid plan for this.You can try to find third-party tools.